# UDP Ports used by an Android Application

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, root-access, nexus-5

I am trying to figure out how to get a complete list of UDP ports opened by a specific PID within a given time interval, on and Android Device. In my current solution I am using a combination of `busybox lsof` and the */proc/net* files.

While */proc/net/tcp*, */proc/net/tcp6*, */proc/net/udp6* are populated by the kernel, */proc/net/udp* is always empty. Is there any reliable alternatives to find UDP sockets opened on Android?

Device: Nexus 5 - Rooted

Android: 4.4.4

Kernel: 3.4.0-gd59db4e android-build@vpbs1.mtv.corp.google.com #1